# jQuery validate ".error" field CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

I am NOT trying to get form validation, I already have validation via the HTML 5 "required" field. What I want to do is be able to control the styles of ".error" which is populated by jQuery validate when a user fails to enter in a field or gives invalid information. How can I control the style if it is not being populated by the jQuery validate function? OR, why does jQuery refuse to provide an error field?

http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/140/

```
    $('#contactForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            first_name: {
                required: true,
            },
            last_name: {
                required: true,
            },
            postal_code: {
                required: true,
            },
            phone_primary: {
                required: true,
            }
            email: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
```

Comment: your browser console shows error after`phone_primary: {`. Its missing a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your `validate`. Every option should be separated by a `,`

```
phone_primary: {
    required: true,
}, //<- missing
email: {
    required: true,
}
```

The `.error` css works - **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvAPY/141/)**

Comment: There is a close reason for typos... just sayin'

Comment: @FelixKling, yes you are right. Out of close votes for the day.